# Mismatch datatype criteria expression, string field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a ms access database and when I try to update a column in a module I get the error "Mismatch datatype criteria expression", when I create the column the datatype was TEXT(25) and the value that I'm trying to assign is a String:

    `Dim str As String
    str = "test"
    sql = "UPDATE Table "
    sql = sql & "SET Table.[column] ='" & str & "' "
    sql = sql & "WHERE Table.[id] = 1;"
    MsgBox(sql)
    Application.CurrentDb.Execute(sql)`

In the `MsgBox` the string of query appears to be right: `"UPDATE Table SET Table.[Column]='test' WHERE Table.[id]=1;`

Which is the error?, how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure Table.[Column] a character type?

Comment: Def looks like you've set your datatype for ID to a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Table.id` is a numeric column your where clause is okay, but if it is a text column it should read:

```sql
WHERE Table.id = '1'
```